# How does one pass ServerSideProps to a nextPage in Nextjs TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Feed from './components/Feed';
import News from './components/News';

import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

import Post from './components/Post';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';

export interface Props {
    value?:value  // this section is giving me the Error 
  }


const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ value }) => {

    
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>



      <div className=" flex  bg-gray-200 space-x-3">
        <Sidebar />
       
        <div className="py-2  flex flex-col">
        <Post/>
        <Feed/>
        </div>
    
        <News value={value} /> // this child component is where I want to pass that the data to so Ic an populate the News Component
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/news');
    const {data: value} = res;
    console.log(value);
    if (!value) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        };
    }
    return {
        props: {
            value
        }
        
        
    };
    
}
```

My aims is to get data from a news API using the SeverSideProps method. Then get that data and pass it to the home page then to a child component. but all I'm getting is an error stating that the value that I returned from the ServerSideProps[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqDIR.png) function can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the type of the value in interface not the value itself.

For example if your value is string do this:

```js
export interface Props {
    value?: string
}
```

Or if it's a custom type, declare that type before and then use it:

```js
interface ValueInterface {
    id: string
    /* other properties */
}

export interface Props {
    value?: ValueInterface
}
```

Or if you don't know its type, you can use **any**:

```js
export interface Props {
    value?: any
}
```

Comment: the respond got returned as an object so now I'm having problems looping through that object properly. the map function can be used on a object so converted  the object to an array using Object.keys(). However, when i do this is has problem finding variables in the array. I'm getting an array of infinite object looping continuously

Comment: Could you share an example of the object and what you want to do with that ?

Comment: Nevermind sir I got it to work , Since I am using typescript all I had to do waste to define that same inerface in the child component after passing the prop and that was it